# Django REST Framework - Define extra arguments using the @action decorator

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm wondering if would be possible to define extra arguments using the `action` decorator:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def follow(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        target_user = ???
        Follow.objects.create(user=user, target=target_user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

What I want to achieve is matching the following path: `api/users/{id}/follow/{target_id}`

The `follow` action will be used to let an user with ID `id` following another user with ID `target_id`.

**UPDATE**:

Since it seems like it's not possible to pass extra args, right now I'm POSTing data as a list of user IDs to be followed:

The serializer to validate data:

```
class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1), required=False, help_text='User target IDs')
```

The action:

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def follow(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = FollowSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.data['user_ids']
            for user_id in user_ids:
                target_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
                Follow.objects.create(user=user, target=target_user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The problem with my solution is that on the auto-generated doc page I'm seeing the form with the `UserSerializer` fields.

[image: API Doc Page]

**UPDATE 2**:

The following *trick* let the auto-generated doc page shows the right form:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'follow':
            return FollowSerializer
        else:
            return UserSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def follow(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

[image: API Doc Page - Correct Form]

Comment: I looked around and hacked for a good 30 minutes, THIS was the trick I was looking for! Nice find.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could pass `target_id` through url as,`api/users/{id}/follow/{target_id}` , but you have to change the views as,

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
    def follow(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        target_user = int(kwargs['target_id'])
        Follow.objects.create(user=user, target=target_user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

and define a ***separate `path()` in urls.py*** as,

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('users/<int:pk>/follow/<int:target_id>/', UserViewSet.as_view({"post": "follow"}))

              ]
```

Answer (score 24):

> The problem with my solution is that on the auto-generated doc page I'm seeing the form with the UserSerializer fields.

From [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

> The decorator can additionally take extra arguments that will be set for the routed view only. For example:

That means that anything that can be used as a class property can also be used as an argument for `@action()`, including `serializer_class`:

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=True, serializer_class=FollowSerializer)
def follow(self, request, pk=None):
    # ...
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    # ...
```

This will result in the correct form appearing in the auto-generated docs.

Comment: this works for django itself, however not for swagger codegen as it appears to always refer to whats delivered by get_serializer_class in viewset

Answer (score 10):

Indeed you can accept extra kwargs as follows DRF 3.13.x without touching routers, neat DRF:

```py
@action(detail=True, methods=['delete'], url_name='media-delete',
        url_path='delete_media/(?P<media_pk>[^/.]+)')
def delete_media(self, request, pk=None, media_pk=None):
    # do your logic
    return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

this will automatically override the default router extra route in response to @action wrapper with ModelViewSet registered routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Looking at the documentation, it seems as though @action() will only accept a certain list of actions obtained by .get_extra_actions()

Can you just use the target's email/account name/account ID as the follow target, then post that data? Seems like that would be the easier way to do it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I already tried and it's working fine. The only problem is that on the auto-generated doc page I don't have the fields defined on `FollowSerializer`, but the ones from `UserSerializer`. I mean it's just the doc page, but ugly to see this. You can check my update

Comment: Maybe I should just create another `APIView`

Comment: There are a lot of Django gurus on here, maybe it's just too early for them. I'm sure somebody will know some arcane way to extend @action()

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was able to fix the issue with the doc page and updated the question. I'll wait for other answers to the original question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fabio so how did fix it? did you have to make a separate view for it?

Comment: @Ken4scholars I used the JPG solution so using the `@action` decorator

Comment: @Fabio thanks. My issue was how to get the docs to use the serializer specified in the action instead of the class serializer. I got it to work using `@swagger_auto_schema` decorator from drf-yasg